# Как интегрировать приложение с поиском в android tv?

Tags: java, android

Не нашел документации на русском языке, а по официальной документации не могу разобраться https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable.html?utm_campaign=ATV-615&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog

Есть сервер и api с поиском по пути [https://example.com/api/search.php?q=Сумерки](https://example.com/api/search.php?q=%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8)
И по документации что-то не могу понять как отловить то что ищет пользователь.

Максимум что получилось это на основе этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497514/content-provider-query-not-being-called-android-tv добиться того чтоб галочка для приложения появилась в настройках поиска

но вот как отловить что ищет пользователь, получить данные по api с сервера и вывести на tv с глобальным поиском, не могу понять